# UICollectionView setContentOffset assertion failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm using Xcode 6 and iOS 8.
I want to set content offset of my Collection View every time I load View Controller.

```
CGFloat offsetY = [self.collectionView layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader atIndexPath:indexPath].frame.origin.y;    
[self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, MIN(self.collectionView.contentSize.height-self.collectionView.bounds.size.height, offsetY-headerHeight)) animated:NO];
```

But I receive this error: `*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]`

What I've tried: `[self.collectionView prepare layout];`
Putting this code in `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` changed nothing.

Comment: What exact value do you set as *Y* value of *contentOffset*? Have you tried ti debug it?